# Counting the number of duplicates for a file descriptor in Linux

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, dup

In Linux, one can duplicate a file descriptor by using the [`dup` command family](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup).

Is there any way to get the count of the number of the duplicates for a file descriptor by way of a system call?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fstat()` on open descriptors. This syscall returns `struct stat`. Duplicate descriptors refer to the same i-node on the same device (`st_dev` and `st_ino` members of `struct stat`).

By runing loop through all open descriptors (You can safely run loop from `0` to `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, ...)` - `stat()` will return -1 for closed descriptors) and checking for unique `st_dev` and `st_ino` You will find duplicates.

*UPDATE:*

After looking closer into `fuser` command on Linux, it seems You can find this info for multiple processes by looking at `/proc/PIF/fd/` folders (build summary of files opened by all or "interesting" processes).

*on FreeBSD similar trick is done by `fstat` command (without mounted `/proc` filesystem), but this approach probably won't be applicable to Linux (haven't checked deeper).*

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear. The solution you gave does not solve my problem. I was passing file descriptors around multiple processes and what I wanted is given a specific FD in ANY of these processes, I should be able to count the number FDs in the system that are referencing the same underlying kernel structure.